# How to remove empty values from the pandas DataFrame from a column type list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Just looking forward a solution to remove empty values from a column which has values as a list in a sense where we are already replacing some strings beforehand, where it's a column of string representation of lists.

In `df.color` we are Just replacing `*._Blue` with empty string:

### Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Bird': ["parrot", "Eagle", "Seagull"], 'color': [ "['Light_Blue','Green','Dark_Blue']", "['Sky_Blue','Black','White', 'Yellow','Gray']", "['White','Jet_Blue','Pink', 'Tan','Brown', 'Purple']"] })

>>> df
      Bird                                              color
0   parrot                 ['Light_Blue','Green','Dark_Blue']
1    Eagle      ['Sky_Blue','Black','White', 'Yellow','Gray']
2  Seagull  ['White','Jet_Blue','Pink', 'Tan','Brown', 'Pu...
```

### Result of above DF:

```
>>> df['color'].str.replace(r'\w+_Blue\b', '')
0                                 ['','Green','']
1           ['','Black','White', 'Yellow','Gray']
2    ['White','','Pink', 'Tan','Brown', 'Purple']
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Usually in python it easily been done as follows..

```
>>> lst = ['','Green','']
>>> [x for x in lst if x]
['Green']
```

I'm afraid if something like below can be done.

```
df.color.mask(df == ' ')
```

Comment: For dataframes that contain lists or other hard to paste objects, you should use `to_dict` to create a [mcve], so that it is easy to re-create.

Comment: @user3483203, sorry for that .. Just updated the info on the post , hope that will helpful.

Comment: So your column isn't a column of lists, it's a column of string representation of lists?

Comment: That's true  @user3483203   added the same in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a column of lists, you have a column that contains string representation of lists.  You can do this all in a single step using `ast.literal_eval` and `str.endswith`.  I would use a list-comprehension  here which should be faster than `apply`

---

```
import ast

fixed = [
    [el for el in lst if not el.endswith("Blue")]
    for lst in df['color'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
]

df.assign(color=fixed)
```

```
      Bird                              color
0   parrot                            [Green]
1    Eagle       [Black, White, Yellow, Gray]
2  Seagull  [White, Pink, Tan, Brown, Purple]
```

Comment: Thnx mile @user3483203 .

Answer (score 3):

You can using the `explode`(pandas 0.25.0) then concat the list back

```
 df['color'].str.replace(r'\w+_Blue\b', '').explode().loc[lambda x : x!=''].groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

Comment: thnx @Wen but  `np.nan` doesn't work in  version `'0.21.0'` , looking for generic solution which may work with almost all versions

Comment: @pygo check the updat e

Comment: It comes with error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @pygo  explode is new in pandas 0.25.0, please update your pandas

Comment: :-)  hmm , okay in that sense we need to have some other way around.. tnx

Answer (score 1):

Another way  using `filter` and `apply`:

```
(df['color'].str.replace(r'\w+_Blue\b', '')
     .apply(lambda x: list(filter(bool, ast.literal_eval(x)))))
```

---

```
0                              [Green]
1         [Black, White, Yellow, Gray]
2    [White, Pink, Tan, Brown, Purple]
```

Comment: thnx @anky_91 :-)