# regex on pandas dataframe column having string representation of lists

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                                                  color
0  ['Light_Blue','Green','Dark_Blue']
1  ['Sky_Blue','Black','White', 'Yellow','Gray']
2  ['White','Jet_Blue','Pink', 'Tan','Brown', 'Purple']
```

### Tried Following with regex:

Using following, it preserves the empty values which i'm looking forward to overcome.

```
>>> df['color'].str.replace(r'\w+_Blue\b', '')
0    ['','Green','']
1    ['','Black','White', 'Yellow','Gray']
2    ['White','','Pink', 'Tan','Brown', 'Purple']
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Desired:

```
                            color
                          [Green]
     [Black, White, Yellow, Gray]
[White, Pink, Tan, Brown, Purple]
```

My Question is how we can achieve that with a `regex` method.

Note: There is an answer for this post with other method using which is  linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511904/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-the-pandas-dataframe-from-a-column-type-list).

Comment: `str` is good for strings, not for a Series of lists

Comment: How is this not a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511904/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-the-pandas-dataframe-from-a-column-type-list?  You shouldn't be looking for other tricks to do this, that is the *right way*

Comment: You should link the last post so you don't get duplicate answers.  Either way, what yatu and myself have provided is the better way to do it, I wouldn't bother looking for a trick to do this with regex

Comment: Wen gave you a solution using regex, what was wrong with that one?

Comment: Wen's Solution only applicable to the pandas version 0.25 not compatible with 0.22.

Comment: Downvoters would you bother to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use a list comprehension for such a problem:

```
df['color'] = [[i for i in r if not i.endswith(tuple(['_Blue', '_']))] 
               for r in df.color]

                color
0                            [Green]
1       [Black, White, Yellow, Gray]
2  [White, Pink, Tan, Brown, Purple]
```

Comment: that's the option as i mentioned in the post but good to your solution.. :-) +1

Comment: Thanks @KarnKumar :)

Comment: [You're going to need ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512258/3483203) since these are string representations of lists.

Comment: They are lists of strings though in this question's input @user3483203

Comment: "I have a dataFrame example below which have a column color that contains string representation of lists"

Comment: Yes I see. Then indeed your solution in the other (same) question is the way to go  @user3483203